# Does webpack allow to run my app without building like jspm?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, browserify, webpack, jspm

I was just wondering about this. Can webpack work in the browser without doing any builds, like JSPM? Or is it the same as browserify?
I looked at the official docs and found no mention of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a module bundler. So closer to Browserify. You can, however, set it up in a watch mode easily. That way it deals with the builds on the background while you develop and examine the result in the browser.